# Is there a reason why electronic training modules always have different UI and navigational widgets?

Tags: end-user-training

I've noticed that corporate electronic training module vary a lot in their UI approach, seemingly reinventing navigation patterns, widget design, visual style every time, even when created by the same vendor.  This was true when I worked at a huge company with deep pockets to create their own training and great UX elsewhere, and working at tiny companies that outsource this work. Is there some functional reason for this? It seems like it would be much cheaper to have a navigational and stylistic framework to plug content into. As well as being much easier to use.